# Sending JSON by POST using Restlet results in "400 Bad request" error

Tags: java, json, post, restlet

When trying to send a *JSON object* to the server using *POST* method, "400 Bad request" error is returned. Standard Java application (SDK) with Restlet api is used to make this request.

Given that the:

- host address is "**http://myhostname.com/api/v1/parts/**"
- access_key is "8QON4KC7BMAYYBCEX"

here is how the code so far looks like:

```
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("http://myhostname.com/api/v1/parts/");

        resource.setMethod(Method.POST);
        resource.getReference().addQueryParameter("format", "json");
        resource.getReference().addQueryParameter("access_key", "8QON4KC7BMAYYBCEX");

            // create json object and populate it
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
               obj.put("partId", "23");
               obj.put("carId", "34");
               obj.put("name", "chassis");
               obj.put("section", "frame");
        } catch (JSONException e1) {// handling of exception}

        StringRepresentation stringRep = new StringRepresentation(obj.toString());
        stringRep.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        try {
               resource.post(stringRep).write(System.out); // exception occurs here
        } catch (Exception e) {// handling of exceptions }
```

Response from server is "400 Bad request". Here is the console output:

```
Bad Request (400) - BAD REQUEST
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:612)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleInbound(ClientResource.java:1202)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1069)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1044)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.post(ClientResource.java:1453)
    at tests.RESTTestReceiverPOST.main(RESTTestReceiverPOST.java:39)
```

When using Chrome [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) plugin to send this json object (and it works with POSTMAN), the output of the POST request looks like this:

```
/api/v1/parts/?format=json&access_key=8QON4KC7BMAYYBCEX HTTP/1.1
Host: myhostname.com
Content-Type: application/json

{ "partId": "23", "carId": "34", "name": "chassis", "section": "frame" }
```

Any suggestions on what may be wrong in the code? Thanks.

Comment: Is that the actual POSTMAN post request? The following `"name": chassis` is not well formed.

Comment: I don't see StringRepresentation Constructor taking a String object? if you convert a json object to a string, all the double quotes would be escaped with a backslash. That may create problems

Comment: In the POSTMAN, json object is added manually ("raw" tab). Now I have updated it.

Comment: @Octopus `String` is a sub type of `CharSequence`.

Comment: @Octopus thanks for the hint. However, when StringRepresantation object is printed in console, it gives this: { "partId": "23", "carId": "34", "name": "chassis", "section": "frame" }

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you so much ;) i didn't know it

Comment: Is there a description of the API anywhere?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Here it is: http://restlet.org/learn/tutorial/2.1/

Comment: Not of restlet, of the `myhostname` site.

Comment: Oh, pardon. There is no real description, but here is a curl request that works (when run directly from server):

curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"partId": 23, "carId": 34, "name": "chassis", "section": "frame"}'  http://localhost:8000/api/v1/receiver/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. You were right @Octopus, there was a problem in this code:

```
   obj.put("partId", "23");
   obj.put("carId", "34");
   obj.put("name", "chassis");
   obj.put("section", "frame");
```

It should look like (numbers without quotes):

```
obj.put("partId", 23);
obj.put("carId", 34);
obj.put("name", "chassis");
obj.put("section", "frame");
```

Thanks again both @Octopus and @Sotirios Delimanolis for your time and help.

Comment: You were misleading us with your sample JSON :P Using that overloaded `put` method will generate `"partId" : 23` instead of `"partId" : "23"`.

Comment: Yup, my bad. Sorry for the mislead :-). Thanks a lot.